# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils

Tags: java, android

I have an Android application, which is working fine. The application have two Java libraries. I installed the newest versions of Eclipse and the Android SDK package on another computer, and I imported in it the same application from the server, but when I run it, the program can't find the java libraries. I tried to remove them from "Build Path Property" and I added them again, but it still gives me this error:

```
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils
```

Do you have any idea how to resolve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have `commons-lang3-<version>.jar` among you libraries? if not this would be a problem. you could get it from a maven repo as: `<dependency org="org.apache.commons" name="commons-lang3" rev="3.1" />`

Comment: yes i have this commons-lang3-3.1.jar in my libraries , but ithe program didn't find it

Comment: can you manually add it to the Eclipse build path, and see if that fixes it? If yes, then go back and reconfigure you build path to include all the jars from "lib"/or your own 3d party dir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem with some other 3rd party library and this solution has helped me

http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17

Comment: thanks, looks interesting, i will follow these instruction and hope to fix it !